# Linearization of nonlinear dynamic system

Tags: dynamical-systems, linearization

I am reading the following paper:

`ergodic theory of chaos and strange attractors, by J.-P. Eckmann` (can be easily downloaded)

My question is around equation (1.7), p. 619:

The separation of two initial points $x(0)$ and $x(0)'$ after time $N$ is

$$x(N) - x(N)' = f^N(x(0))-f^N(x(0)') \approx \bigg[ \frac{d}{dx}(f^N)(x(0)) \bigg] [x(0)-x(0)']$$

From this approximation, I  get $$ f^N(x(0)) \approx \bigg[ \frac{d}{dx}(f^N)x(0) \bigg] x(0)$$ Consider $N = 1$,$$x(1) =  f(x(0)) \approx \bigg[ \frac{d}{dx}(f)(x(0)) \bigg] x(0)$$

I am confused about what I remember in the following. Suppose $y = f(x)$ and I know $y_0 = f(x_0)$ so I can obtain the following $$y_0+\delta y = \bigg[\frac{d}{dx}(f)(x_0)\bigg]\delta x + f(x_0),$$ where $\frac{d}{dx}(f)(x_0)$ is the slope of $f$ at $x_0$.

What I should have is $\delta x$ instead of $x(0)$

Comment: How did you get the second display from the first? There is nothing like that in Eckmann and Ruelle's paper on p. 619.

Comment: @user539887 The second display is just multiplication of the $\bigg[ \cdot\bigg]$ and the $x(0)$. This step is what I think and not sure if I can do this.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. The first display says just that the increment of the dependent variable (that is, $f^N(x(0))-f^N(x(0)')$, is approximately equal to the derivative times the increment of the independent variable (that is, $x(0)-x(0)'$).

Comment: @user539887 I get it, thanks!